# My discord bot is not running and shows error in running client

Tags: python, discord

So I'm a new coder in python working on this discord bot and it won't work. I looked at the error and it says its stems from line 4's client.run() function. It said I needed "intents" and that they were not specified, so I just looked it up and tried to fix it by adding intents, but it still doesn't work. Could you help me please?

Here's the code:

```
import discord
import time
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client()
def run_bot():
  token = "TOKEN"
  client.run(token)  

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("BorkBot v 1.0 release")
  print("A discord bot by Rishi Suresh")
  print("Login Successful at", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "as {0.user}".format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
      return
  elif message.content.startswith("/hello"):
    await message.channel.send("Bork Bork discord go brrrrrrrrrr")
  elif message.content.startswith("/help"):
    await message.channel.send("idk look at the docs you idiot")
  else:
    print
run_bot()
```

PS I know I shouldnt be really using stack overflow like this, but I didnt know where else to go for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this when initialising the intents and clients.

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also, you may want to remove your token from the code before posting it